# the corresponding modular form of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-representations, modular-forms, elliptic-modular-form

The modularity theorem reveals the relationship between elliptic curves and modular forms. Is there a series of steps or an algorithm such that we can obtain the corresponding modular form, when given an elliptic curve defined over the field of rational numbers?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

(a)  You compute the conductor of your elliptic curve (say using Tate's algorithm, or some variant).

(b) You then compute all the weight two Hecke eigenforms at that level (using modular symbols).

(c) You determine how many $q$-expansion coefficients you need to distinguish the different eigenforms.  (Either by inspection, or theoretically, using the Sturm bound.)  This gives a finite number of $a_p$'s that you need to compute to recognize your desired eigenform.

(d) You compute sufficiently many $a_p$'s for your elliptic curve to determine which eigenform it matches with.

In practice, unless your elliptic curve has an absolutely enormous conductor, this work will have already been done (most likely by Cremona), and you can just look at the existing tables (now incorporated into the 
$L$-functions and modular forms database [here](http://www.lmfdb.org)).

Comment: NB: John Cremona has written a lovely book called "Algorithms for Modular Elliptic Curves" explaining precisely how this is actually done in practice -- the hard work is mostly in step (b).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler About (a) let an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$ and we are told $\prod_{p \text{ good reduction}} \frac1{1-a_p p^{-s}+p^{1-2s}}, a_p = p+1-\#E(F_p)$ is an eigenform, of level $N=\prod_{p \text{ bad reduction}} p^{e_p}$, is there an easy way to upper bound $N$, if not which theorem does the bound on $N$ come from ?

Comment: @reuns All of your questions are answered in Cremona's book. Part of the Modularity Theorem is the assertion that the level of the eigenform equals the conductor of the curve, which can be computed directly from a Weierstrass equation via Tate's algorithm. (By the way, your comment seems to be confusing the eigenform and its L-function; and you are omitting the Euler factors at primes of bad multiplicative reduction, which are non-trivial.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler (it stays an eigenform without its bad Euler factors). It seems Tate is computing the ramification of $E$, looking only at the finitely many $p$ dividing its discriminant we can describe the ramification of $\Bbb{Q}_p(E[p^k])/\Bbb{Q}_p$ with finitely many computable integers. Something can be done similarly for the level $N$ modular jacobian, but only once $N$ is fixed. To bound the modular conductor of $E$ do we need to relate $N$ with the ramification of (quotients of) $J_0(N)$ for general $N$ ?

Comment: @reuns (yes, but its level may change). Given E, Tate's algorithm computes an integer N, the conductor of E, which measures the ramification of the curve. Part of the modularity theorem states that this N which Tate's algorithm for E computes is also the minimal possible level of an eigenform attached to E.